# 2d char array initialization in c

Tags: c, arrays

**my goal is to initialize a 2d char array with spaces.**

```
 #define LEN 9

// in main function
char ticTacToe[LEN][LEN];
initialize_2D_Array(ticTacToe, LEN);

void initialize_2D_Array(char array[][LEN], int len)
{
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        initialize_1D_Array(array[i], len);
    }
}
void initialize_1D_Array( char array[], int len)
{
    for (int i=0; i< len; i++)
    {
        array[i] = ' '; // space
    }
}
```

// edit: i changed the type of ticTacToe to char but the problem remains.

[the input i have got - it looks like it just initiazlied just some of the elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZeI2.png)

[this is the output i am looking forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8eZ5.png)

Comment: You pass `ìnt`s to where `char`s are expected. Why?

Comment: `int ticTacToe[LEN][LEN];` <=> `char array[][LEN]`, `int` and `char` are type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

```
(int ticTacToe[LEN][LEN];)
```

is type of `int` but in your function

```
void initialize_2D_Array(char array[][LEN], int len)
```

the data type is `char`

You have to change data type of the array `(int ticTacToe[LEN][LEN])` from `int` to `char`.